# COCOS 2d V2.x Menu Alignment Issue - Tested in iPhone Simulator 5.1 and iPhone 4 Device 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Not sure why the menu is aligned to Top Left corner , previous version the menu was aligned perfectly to the center. Testing in iPhone 4.

I know the solution `[menu setPosition:ccp( size.width/2, size.height/2)];` but wanted to understand why its Aligned to Top Left.

To get the same result please try this in AppDelegate

```
[director_ pushScene: [HelloWorldLayer scene]];
```

instead of

```
[director_ pushScene: [IntroLayer scene]];
```

**My Result and my Code**

[image]

UPDATED SOURCE

MenuLayer.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface MenuLayer : CCLayer {

}

+(CCScene *) scene;

@end
```

MenuLayer.m

```
#import "MenuLayer.h"


@implementation MenuLayer

        +(CCScene *) scene
        {
            CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

            MenuLayer *layer = [MenuLayer node];

            [scene addChild: layer];

            return scene;
        }

    -(id) init
    {
        if( (self=[super init]) ) {
            CCMenuItem *itemAchievement = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Play" block:^(id sender) {}];
            CCMenuItem *itemLeaderboard = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Settings" block:^(id sender) {}];

            CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:itemAchievement, itemLeaderboard, nil];

            [menu alignItemsVertically];

            [self addChild:menu];
        }
        return self;
    }
    @end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
    [director_ pushScene: [MenuLayer scene]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'll tell you the answer first:

You have something gone wrong :) .. You must have changed the position of the parent, or its grandparent, ... etc.

**EDIT:**

Your error is running `CCDirector` inside this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ...
    // Remove this code ! 
    [director_ runWithScene:blah];
}
```

Instead, you must run the `CCDirector` like so:

```
// This method is part of the CCDirectorDelegate methods
// Add it below the - (BOOL)application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
-(void) directorDidReshapeProjection:(CCDirector*)director
{
    if(director.runningScene == nil) {
        // Add the first scene to the stack. The director will draw it immediately into the framebuffer. (Animation is started automatically when the view is displayed.)
        // and add the scene to the stack. The director will run it when it automatically when the view is displayed.
        [director_ runWithScene: [HelloWorldLayer scene]];
    }
}
```

**Evidence:**

Read the cocos2d docs! They say that if you are running on iOS versions prior to iOS 6, you mustn't run the `CCDirector` inside the `application: didFinishLaunching:` method.

From the docs:

> This is needed for iOS4 and iOS5 in order to ensure
>   that the 1st scene has the correct dimensions
>   This is not needed on iOS6 and could be added to the application:didFinish...

Here is your pic, dissected:

[image]

That's a total mess... There is no way cocos2d default behavior is like that. Create a new cocos2d v2.x, and clean up `HelloWorldLayer.m`, and here is the result:

```
// Achievement Menu Item using blocks
CCMenuItem *itemAchievement = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Achievements" block:^(id sender) {}];
// Leaderboard Menu Item using blocks
CCMenuItem *itemLeaderboard = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Leaderboard" block:^(id sender) {}];

CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:itemAchievement, itemLeaderboard, nil];

[menu alignItemsVertically];

[self addChild:menu];
```

[image]

Comment: I have been working on cocos2d for almost 6+ months , but this alignment issue I have no clue. Since you have its a total so I created a new Test Project (v 2.x) and created a new file called MenuLayer which extends CCLayer and it has one Static method for Scene (as usual). Tested both in iPhone 5.1 Simulator and iPhone 4 - Same result.

Comment: Create a sample project and Please try this in Appdelegate  [director_ pushScene: [HelloWorldLayer scene]]; instead of  [director_ pushScene: [IntroLayer scene]];

Comment: @Anandh OK, I found your error. Please check the edits. You had something wrong, I knew it!

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by finding `-(void) makeTransition:(ccTime)dt` in **IntroLayer.m** and add replace following code:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[HelloWorldLayer scene] withColor:ccWHITE]];
```

by

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[YourLayer scene] withColor:ccWHITE]];
```

Answer (score 0):

It works by modifying the MenuLayer.m - override onEnter and then add the Children to that layer

```
#import "MenuLayer.h"


@implementation MenuLayer

+(CCScene *) scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    MenuLayer *layer = [MenuLayer node];

    [scene addChild: layer];

    return scene;
}
-(void) onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    CCMenuItem *itemAchievement = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Play" block:^(id sender) {}];
    CCMenuItem *itemLeaderboard = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Settings" block:^(id sender) {}];

    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:itemAchievement, itemLeaderboard, nil];

    [menu alignItemsVertically];

    [self addChild:menu];

}
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```